# Using Cocoapods in Cocoa Touch Framework?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

I'm developing a framework that requires use of AFNetworking. So I started by creating a new and shiny *Cocoa Touch Framework* and as usual I created a pod file with the following stuff in it:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

Obviously on a normal project this would create the workspace and everything would be super smooth... But since I picked *Cocoa Touch Framework* I am not able to import *AFNetowrking.h* into my *ProjectName.h*. The error I'm getting is:

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module...

So I actually looked this up! It seemed that all I need to do is to go to my build settings and set *Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules* to yes and my problem will be solved... but that didn't help either.

Another thing I tried doing was to also set the target membership of AFNetworking.h header file to *public*. But that didn't resolve the issue and I'm still getting the same error.

I'd appreciate if anyone can give me a step by step mini guide on how to do this?

It is worth mentioning that I'd like to be able to use the AFNetworking library in swift as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
use_frameworks!
```

You need to make sure you install the beta version of CocoaPod (0.36). The only issue with this is that **you will be able to run it on iOS 7** but ***it will not pass the validation on apple application submission*** (keep that in mind).

Answer (score 0):

When importing a module using cocoapods in your source code you must import it like

`#import <AFNetworking.h>`

rather than

`#import "AFNetworking.h"`

Comment: This didn't make any difference @farhan... :(