# Cocoa Touch Framework Dependencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a **Cocoa Touch Framework**. To create a framework is not a problem, I used [this tutorial](http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/create-ios-cocoa-touch-framework-using-xcode/) and it is good.

I need to use third party libraries inside: like openssl, XLForm, AFNetworking. I know that it is not correct to include them in my framework, I need to create a dependencies, but I can't find how to do this.

Moreover is it possible to use pods in my framework and just make dependencies to these libs. So user which will include my framework to his project will need just install these pods.

Comment: If you are using non-system frameworks/libraries, then they must be included with your framework.  There is no alternative.

Comment: @Droppy it is not correct way to include non-system frameworks inside, because user can use them in his own project and in this case he will get linker duplication.

Comment: What linker duplication?  The framework and app are linked in separate steps.  Static libraries will cause linker duplication but I assume you are talking about dynamic libraries?

Comment: For example if I install Pods in my Framework and in my Project I will get a warning like: Class XLFormBaseCell is implemented in both <Framework path> and <Project path>. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: And that's a linker or a runtime warning (like "X class is implemented in two different places...")?

Comment: No, it is command line warning while app launched, anyway it seems I found solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found solution.

Thanks to @Droppy and thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374582/using-cocoapods-in-cocoa-touch-framework).

What I did: I just installed pods to my Framework project but used this **use_frameworks!** key.
Then I dragged my Framework to my Project and installed pods there, also with same key, otherwise (when pod wasn't installed in my Project) I was getting error like:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XLForm.framework/XLForm...
```

I used XLForm inside my Framework.